# Availale tools for tuning ranking models in sharepoint 2013 search?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search

Is there any tool available for tuning custom or existing ranking models in SharePoint search. Or we have to improve relevancy using available options in SharePoint search like query rules, authorities etc? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Is there a specific issue you are having with search?

Comment: Yes I crawled some websites and external repositories, and I want to improve search relevance. There are no of options available in SharePoint to improve search relevancy. but I want to add some custom ranking model for tuning according to my needs. Creating custom ranking model without using any available tool is quite difficult task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen much in the way of third party products that affect search ranking. Most books say to use the tools exposed through the central admin UI to affect page ranking, like authorative pages.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It's a tool for tuning the ranking model.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/ranking-model-tuning-WA104192565.aspx?queryid=d2bccb36-7023-410b-976d-5d6be52ca946&css=ranking%20model&CTT=1

If you want to do it more manually, try this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn169052(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn169052%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)